# How can i schedule multiple redshift (plpgsql) stored procedure in Airflow

Tags: python, stored-procedures, airflow, amazon-redshift, plpgsql

How can i schedule  multiple redshift (plpgsql) stored procedure in Airflow using python  ?

for eg.

```
call stored_p_1() ;

call stored_p_2() ;

call stored_p_3() ;
```

I want all of tasks to be running in parallel and all of them are independent of each other (except slight exception described in the end), weekly schedule interval that i want to keep

Also how to add the config and other details of database credential for connection, would be nice if one can share

**PS:**
I want `stored_p_1` to be run slightly before than other ones but also other `stored_p_%d` should not wait for `stored_p_1` to be completed also.

This happens because `stored_p_1` writes some data in a target table during the first few minutes of run  and that written data from target table gets accessed by the other rest of the stored procedures to operate

The above kind of violates the acyclic graph criterion thus if there any trick that can work

Comment: you need to provide more information. will the task(stored procedure) be running at the same time or different schedule? are the task dependent on each other? it will help if provide more information on the objective of this question and snippets of your dag(s)

Comment: Added the requested information